# Windows 7 drivers for Lenovo Thinkpad T400

Tags: windows-7, drivers, thinkpad

I've been playing with versions of Windows 7 since PDC last year and finally installed the RTM version 2 weeks ago. However, even given a year head-notice, it seems like Lenovo has not updated all their drivers to fit the new OS. The one I (and many others) am missing the most is support for switchable graphics.
The only resource I could find on my own was this [Windows 7 Driver beta page](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/WIN7-BETA.html) - and a lot of questions on a lot of forums.

My question: is there an official version of all the drivers planned soon? Can someone point me to a more updated repository? And does someone know how to get support for switchable graphics in 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question on the official Lenovo forums and there was no answer regarding date or confirmation of availability. Someone said it should be around the Windows 7 release date. I presume they are working on it.

Comment: I sincerely hope so. HP and even Sony got theirs out already. You would think Lenovo engineers couldn't get their hands on the beta/RC :)

Comment: I think they've done a pretty good job with the rest of the drivers. I'm not sure why there is a delay with the graphics drivers.

Comment: ...and the audio drivers. I'm getting horrible sound levels from the default Windows audio driver. Well, hope you're right and we'll all get full support come October...

Answer (score 5):

People! Good news! [This link](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/WIN7-BETA.html#m8xswitch) was just added to the drivers page.

Comment: Good link!  I've been using it for a while and most of the programs work pretty well!

Answer (score 3):

[From an employee in the Windows 7 section of the Lenovo forums](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-7-RTM-Discussion/ETA-on-Final-Windows-7-Driver-Support/m-p/153768#M2320):

> Ok, This is pretty much as "official"
>   as it's gonna get.  Lenovo will post
>   final Win 7 WHQL certified drivers on
>   or about October 22 to coincide with
>   the official Microsoft release date of
>   Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

As someone answered on another thread on Windows 7 on a Z61 - maybe they are waiting fior the "official release" which is a pain as I cant wait to dump Vista ...

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 won't officially support switchable graphics. your best bet with the T400 is to go into the BIOS and turn off switchable graphics.

Comment: It's not Windows 7 that needs to support it - it's Lenovo who need to publish the right driver. Since they keep selling switchable graphics machines even now, I'd imagine they plan to support them.